# Backpropagation in a convolutional neural network with stride and padding

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, convolution, backpropagation, javascript

So i am trying to learn backpropagation of convolutional neural networks. A lot of articles only cover convolutions without a stride and a padding variable, so i decided to try it on my own.
For simplicity i decided to try correlation (no filter flipping).
Symbols:

$O$ = output
$W1$ = output width
$H1$ = output height
$I$ = input
$F$ = filter
$FS$ = filter size (filter width and height are the same and equal to $FS$)

So I defined the correlation as:
$$\label{1}\tag{1} O_{i,j} = \sum_{x = 0}^{FS-1}\sum_{y = 0}^{FS-1}I_{x+i*s-p, y+j*s-p}*F_{x,y}$$

#### Filter derivative:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial F_{i,j}} = \sum_{k=0}^{W1-1}\sum_{h=0}^{H1-1}\frac{\partial E}{\partial O_{k,h}}\frac{\partial O_{k,h}}{\partial F_{i,j}}$$
$$\frac{\partial O_{k,h}}{\partial F_{i,j}} = \frac{\partial }{\partial F_{i,j}}\left [ \sum_{x = 0}^{FS-1}\sum_{y = 0}^{FS-1}I_{x+k*s-p, y+h*s-p}*F_{x,y} \right ]$$
Derivative is non zero only when $x = i$ and $y = j$, therefore:
$$ \frac{\partial O_{k,h}}{\partial F_{i,j}} = I_{i+k*s-p, j+h*s-p} $$
and
$$\label{2}\tag{2} \frac{\partial E}{\partial F_{i,j}} = \sum_{k=0}^{W1-1}\sum_{h=0}^{H1-1}\frac{\partial E}{\partial O_{k,h}}I_{i+k*s-p, j+h*s-p}$$

#### Code attempt:

So i wanted to try if my calculations were correct, so i wrote this simple correlation and backpropagation in javascript:
https://gist.github.com/jakic12/414ad450d9c1222e58d8e09c6b92cebb

First the forward propagation (correlation) - [equation (1)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/backpropagation-in-a-convolutional-neural-network-with-stride-and-padding#mjx-eqn-1)

```js
/**
 * correlate an array `a` with a filter `f`
 * @param{*} a the input array
 * @param{*} f the filter
 * @param{*} s stride
 * @param{*} p padding
 */
function corre(a, f, s, p){
    let outY = parseInt((a.length - f.length + 2 * p)/s + 1)
    let outX = parseInt((a[0].length - f[0].length + 2 * p)/s + 1)

    return new Array(outY).fill(0).map((_, y) => 
        new Array(outX).fill(0).map((__, x) => {
            let sum = 0;
            for(let j = 0; j < f.length; j++){
                for(let i = 0; i < f[j].length; i++){
                    if(a[y + j * s - p] && a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p])
                        sum += a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p] * f[y][x]
                }
            }
            return sum
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Then the error calculation (Mean squared error) and the partial derivatives with respect to the output layer ($\frac{\partial E}{\partial O_{k,h}}$)

```js
/**
 * Calculate the error and the partial derivatives with respect to the output layer
 * @param{*} actual the actual output
 * @param{*} exp the expected output
 */
function getError(actual, exp){
    let err = 0
    let out = new Array(actual.length).fill(0).map(() => new Array(actual[0].length))

    for(let i = 0; i < out.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < out[i].length; j++){
            out[i][j] = actual[i][j] - exp[i][j]
            err += Math.pow(exp[i][j] - actual[i][j],2)
        }
    }
    return { dO:out, err:err/2 }
}
```

Then calculating the derivatives with respect to the filter - [equation (2)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/backpropagation-in-a-convolutional-neural-network-with-stride-and-padding#mjx-eqn-2)

```js
/**
 * backpropagate the correlation with given derivatives of the next layer
 * @param{*} FS filter size
 * @param{*} dO derivative with respect to the output of the correlation
 * @param{*} input the input of the correlation
 * @param{*} s stride
 * @param{*} p  pad
 */
function backpropFilter(FS, dO, input, s, p){
    return new Array(FS).fill(0).map((_, j) =>
        new Array(FS).fill(0).map((__, i) => {
            let sum = 0
    
            for(let h = 0; h < dO.length; h++){
                for(let k = 0; k < dO[h].length; k++){          
                    if(j+h*s-p >= 0 && j+h*s-p < input.length && i+k*s-p >= 0 && i+k*s-p < input[0].length)
                        sum += dO[h][k] * input[j+h*s-p][i+k*s-p]
                }
            }
            return sum
            }
        )
    )
}
```

#### The problem

The problem is, that altho the network first starts descending, it then quickly starts going up and never stops:
[image: Error graph when learning with 10000 iterations]

I am sorry, because i am not the best at derivatives, so i don't know where my problem is.
Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the code:

```js
/**
 * correlate an array `a` with a filter `f`
 * @param{*} a the input array
 * @param{*} f the filter
 * @param{*} s stride
 * @param{*} p padding
 */
function corre(a, f, s, p){
    let outY = parseInt((a.length - f.length + 2 * p)/s + 1)
    let outX = parseInt((a[0].length - f[0].length + 2 * p)/s + 1)

    return new Array(outY).fill(0).map((_, y) => 
        new Array(outX).fill(0).map((__, x) => {
            let sum = 0;
            for(let j = 0; j < f.length; j++){
                for(let i = 0; i < f[j].length; i++){
                    if(a[y + j * s - p] && a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p])
                        sum += a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p] * f[y][x]
                }
            }
            return sum
            }
        )
    )
}
```

```js
sum += a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p] * f[y][x]
                                           ^  ^
```

should be

```js
sum += a[y + j * s - p][x + i * s - p] * f[j][i]
                                           ^  ^
```